# OpenTelemetry Spring boot starter problems when Springdocs are enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, open-telemetry

I am trying to setup my app to export logs/traces/metrics over OTLP and to do so I am using the corresponding Spring boot starter as is mentioned [here](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/spring-boot/). I have imported both the BOMs as mentioned and added the starter as a dependency in my project and the setup looks OK for the most part.

However when I try to run the application I get the following error:

```java
16:44:39.629 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otelInstrumentationWithSpanAspect' defined in class path resource [io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/spring/autoconfigure/instrumentation/annotations/InstrumentationAnnotationsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'otelInstrumentationWithSpanAspect' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: parameterNameDiscoverer,localSpringDocParameterNameDiscoverer
16:44:39.635 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.sdk.logs.SdkLoggerProvider - Calling shutdown() multiple times.
16:44:39.636 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.e.internal.grpc.GrpcExporter - Calling shutdown() multiple times.
16:44:39.636 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.sdk.metrics.SdkMeterProvider - Multiple close calls
16:44:39.636 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.e.internal.grpc.GrpcExporter - Calling shutdown() multiple times.
16:44:39.636 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.sdk.trace.SdkTracerProvider - Calling shutdown() multiple times.
16:44:39.636 [restartedMain] INFO  i.o.e.internal.grpc.GrpcExporter - Calling shutdown() multiple times.
16:44:39.637 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
16:44:39.649 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
16:44:39.657 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method otelInstrumentationWithSpanAspect in io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.spring.autoconfigure.instrumentation.annotations.InstrumentationAnnotationsAutoConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - parameterNameDiscoverer: defined by method 'parameterNameDiscoverer' in class path resource [io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/spring/autoconfigure/instrumentation/annotations/InstrumentationAnnotationsAutoConfiguration.class]
    - localSpringDocParameterNameDiscoverer: defined by method 'localSpringDocParameterNameDiscoverer' in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/configuration/SpringDocConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

It seems to me that there is conflict between the `ParameterNameDiscoverer` bean of the `InstrumentationAnnotationsAutoConfiguration` and the one by `SpringDocConfiguration` class. My question is how can one overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been fixed in the latest release 2.0.0 - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/pull/10105

Answer (score -1):

You just have to configure the DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer as the Primary one as Opentelemetry wants.
By adding your own config

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {
    public Configuration() {
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ParameterNameDiscoverer parameterNameDiscoverer() {
        return new DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer();
    }
}
```